PHP 8.4 - asymmetric visibility
I compiled php 8.4 from source code to try some features. I have this code.
<?php

class PrefixStyle
{
    public private(set) string $phone {
        get {
            return $this->phone;
        }
        set {
            $this->phone = $value;
        }
    }
}

$foo = new PrefixStyle();
$foo->phone = "123 456 789";

var_dump($foo->phone);

It works. Output is string(11) "123 456 789". I think, that 16. line should trigger error, because I have private(set), and I cannot do $foo->phone = "123 456 789"; Why it does not work?
This example trigger error.
<?php

class PrefixStyle
{
    public private(set) string $phone;
}

$foo = new PrefixStyle();
$foo->phone = "123 456 789";

var_dump($foo->phone);

I think the previous one should throw out the error as well.

Maybe it will throw an error in future. I think this somewhat unclear for me The behavior of the property is otherwise unchanged, aside from the restricted visibility.

I'm not sure what tag you meant to use when you selected feature-extraction. That's related to image processing, so I removed it.
